# Datagrid Column Binding To Class

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have a DataGrid to show Products of Type ProductModel. And within each Product I have a ProductType of Type ProductTypeModel. I am not able to bind properties of this ProductTypeModel class to datagrid column.

Binding of other properties like Id, UserId, ProductLotNumber etc. works fine and shows on datagrid. Only thing I colund't get to to show is ProductType and it's nested properties.

(I am using Caliburn.Micro)

Here is ProductModel

```
public class ProductModel : IProductionInputItemModel, IProductionOutputItemModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ProductTypeModel ProductType { get; set; }
    public string ProductLotNumber { get; set; }
    public int CropYear { get; set; }
    public string ProductNote { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

}
```

and here is the  ProductTypeModel

```
public class ProductTypeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAseptic { get; set; }
    public bool IsPuree { get; set; }
    public bool IsPureeConcentrate { get; set; }
    public bool IsClearJuice { get; set; }
    public bool IsCloudyJuice { get; set; }
    public bool IsClearConcentrate { get; set; }
    public bool IsCloudyConcentrate { get; set; }
    public bool IsOrganic { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to show ProductName, and other boolean properties that are true in a stackpanel in a cell. But I couldn't figure out how.

Here is what I could come up until now but couldn't make it work:

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                ...
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                ...
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Products">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            Ürün Türü
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductType.ProductName}"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Purple" FontSize="8" Text="Aseptik " Visibility="{Binding ProductType.IsAseptic, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="DarkGreen" FontSize="8" Text="Organik " Visibility="{Binding ProductType.IsOrganic, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="Püre " FontSize="8" Visibility="{Binding ProductType.IsPuree, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="Püre Konsantre " FontSize="8" Visibility="{Binding ProductType.IsPureeConcentrate, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="Berrak NFC " FontSize="8" Visibility="{Binding ProductType.IsClearJuice, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="Bulanık NFC " FontSize="8" Visibility="{Binding ProductType.IsCloudyJuice, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="Berrak Konsantre " FontSize="8" Visibility="{Binding ProductType.IsClearConcentrate, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="Bulanık Konsantre " FontSize="8" Visibility="{Binding ProductType.IsCloudyConcentrate, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lot Numarası" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>

            </DataGrid>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Also the viewmodel here :

```
public class ProductViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _events;
    private readonly IProductEndPoint _productEndPoint;

    public ProductViewModel(IEventAggregator events, IProductEndPoint productEndPoint)
    {
        _events = events;
        _productEndPoint = productEndPoint;
    }

    private BindableCollection<ProductModel> _products;

    public BindableCollection<ProductModel> Products
    {
        get { return _products; }
        set
        {
            _products = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Products);
        }
    }


    protected override async void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        base.OnViewLoaded(view);
        var products = await _productEndPoint.GetAllProducts();
        Products = new BindableCollection<ProductModel>(products);
    }
}
```

Comment: check VS Output window for any binding errors. I don't know which binding conventions caliburn.micro uses, but I would try to set ItemsSource directly: `DataGrid.ItemsSource  = products;`. Column bindings look fine to me

Comment: Binding of other properties like Id, UserId, ProductLotNumber etc. works fine and shows on datagrid. Only thing I colund't get to to show is ProductType and it's nested properties.

Comment: sound like it might be `null` (not loaded properly)

Comment: I tried your code with some minor modifications and it worked with the latest release candidate,  I added this to where the datagrid is declared in the xaml  AutoGenerateColumns="False"

Comment: Also bound the second column to  ProductLotNumber                   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lot Numarası" Binding="{Binding ProductLotNumber}" />

Comment: Since the code was not included to for you boolean to visibility converter I removed the horizontal stack panel.

Comment: I sample project is here https://github.com/vb2ae/StackOverFlowQuestion

Comment: Another recommendation is to set up a logger to see what is going on with the binding.  the above repo has once included